# Need a Perforce DVCS recommendation: git-p4, hg Perfarce, or Something Else?

Tags: git, mercurial, perforce

We're getting migrated from Subversion to Perforce at work. I've been using git-svn and it's kept me very productive. I want to keep using a DVCS for my own development.

Which works best with Perforce in your experience, git-p4, Perfarce (hg) or something else I've never heard of?

What works well (and what doesn't)?

Comment: I have had only bad luck so far with hg perfarce extension dying on check outs with p4 client aborts on missing files.  I really like Mercurial and hope to find a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

If you already know git, I would recommend to just go with git-p4.  It has a small job to do, but it performs that job reasonably well.  Unfortunately, the documentation is rather sparse.  Make sure to get a newer version of git-p4.

I recently did some slides on using git-p4.

http://www.slideshare.net/mkramer2/git-censoredkey

Answer (score 0):

following on @masonk, use git-p4.